# storm pillar and huge creatures

Tags: dnd-4e, powers

Last game session I had a rule problem with storm pillar.

The creature moved into a square adjacent to the pillar so took the damage.
He moved through and so hit a new square adjacent to the pillar.

- Does he take damage for each square adjacent to the pillar or just one?
- Does every part of his body trigger the attack? (for huge part one hits square a1 hen he moves forward and part 2 of the body hits a1, so if a1 is a adjacent square he gets 2 times damage from passing a1)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It would only trigger one time (regardless of creature size). Typically damage like that only happens the first time and any subsequent movement is not penalized.